# How to perform Migration of Jira & Confluence Server to Data Center

Tags: jira, confluence

We have currently the following server products:

1- Jira Core

2- Confluence

We are targeting to deploy the corresponding Data Center offering of each.

For Jira Core, we are thinking of Jira Software.

I'm seeking a step-by-step guide to accomplish this and a reference to Infrastructure sizing.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to update license: https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/upgrade-from-jira-server-to-jira-data-center-993929572.html

Optionally if you would like to add more Jira / Confluence nodes there are official guides:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/set-up-a-jira-data-center-cluster-993929600.html
https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/set-up-a-confluence-data-center-cluster-982322030.html

It is matter of properly setting up server and Jira/Confluence properties.